# AdMob ads not showing up at all

Tags: android, sdk, admob, manifest

So i downloaded the latest admob sdk. Followed all the instructions by importing it into the project, etc.

Then i did the thing that allows ads in 2.3.3 also by changing project.properties target to android-13 and set min-sdk to 10.

Also declared this in the manifest :

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Declared the AdView in the XML like this :

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="xxxxxx"    <!--replaced xxxxxx with publisher id-->
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="xxxxx"  <!--replaced xxxxx with device id-->
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

After all of this the ad simply doesnt show up!!
In grapical layout it says class could not be instantiated

Where have i gone wrong?

Comment: What class does it say can't be instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

Do you include the `admob.jar` file in your project `libs` directory?

Comment: yes. I added the GoogleAdmobAdsAndroidSDK.jar to /libs in my project.

Comment: so i removed the internet and network_state_access permissions, and the AdView became visible as a red box with an error in it saying internet permissions required. As soon as i corrected those errors , it disappeared again

Comment: BTW if i remove internet permissions in the manifest, the ad shows up as a red box saying internet access required

Comment: I am having the same issue. I can't figure it out. I am trying to get ads to work on 2.3.3 using the new 6.0.1 admob sdk.

Comment: @NealCaffrey are you still having this problem? Do you have information on what class can't be instantiated? Perhaps you could post the log from when you have this problem.

Comment: The problem was solved. Uhhhh, no laughing. I had an AdBlocker enabled :)